# Is Magneto's daughter a mutant?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse

Speaking specifically of *X-Men: Apocalypse*, there is a scene early on where she's surrounded by woodland critters (mostly deer and caribou it looks like) which seem super docile.

There doesn't seem to be much backstory in the movie on her, but that scene seemed to imply to me that she either had some kind of mutant power for taming animals or else they're running some kind of weird petting zoo.

I'll accept either answers specifically about the movie, or about the comic character his movie daughter was based on (if there was one).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### As stated by Jontia, yes, Nina is a mutant.

While this is never explicitly states it seems clear enough from the film that she has the ability to communicate and control animals. She calls upon a flock of birds to attack the police officers before she is killed.

> Police Officer: What's happening? **She is one of them**.
> [...]
> Police Officer: **Make her stop**.
>
> Erik: She **can't control them**.
> [...]
> Erik: She's frightened.
>
> Nina: I'm not letting them take you! I'm not letting them take you!
>
> Police Officer: Make it stop!
> [...]
> Erik: No. No, Nina! . Nina? Nina. No. Don't... Please. Please. Please. What have you done? Not my babies. Not my babies. IS THIS WHAT YOU WANT FROM ME? Is this what I am? Is this what I am

The police clearly point out that the animals seem to be attacking them based on Nina's command. And while Erik's first defence is that it's not her, in desperation he clarifies that due to her fear she is unaware that she is controlling them and that she can't do anything to help it.

The clip can be found below. However, there are no subtitles to the polish, unfortunately... I will work on this when I get time. The scene still clearly portrays Nina's powers manipulating the birds to attack the officers.

Comment: Will try to remember to provide a clip when I find time.

Comment: Wow, I must've slept through that part, yes it does seem obvious now!

Comment: I found the clip. But is in German and doesn't have subtitles

Comment: @Juan, I'll look into it, but I should be able to get one up now.

Comment: @Gnemlock, Argh poo, so we can't have a clip because I've breached copyright ground. HBO and New Line normally just block me from monetising my videos :(

Comment: Odd. Perhaps it's region locked, though it's odd that it doesn't just say that. It usually would say "blocked.. in your region".

Comment: @Gnemlock I checked in incognito and it is blocked for sure. This one appears to work

Comment: I speak Polish. The dead givaway is that her mother is saying "Nina. Nina, STOP!" (Nina, Nina Przestan). She also screams "I won't allow them to take you" (Nie pozwole im ci zabrac). My diacritics are wrong.

Answer (score 8):

Yes.

[Nina Gurzsky](http://xmenmovies.wikia.com/wiki/Nina_Gurzsky) was shot and killed in the forest by police. She was a mutant and displayed the ability to communicate/control animals in the X-Men : Apocalypse film.

Comment: You are correct, and in this case the wikia is correct, but we generally prefer (and upvote) answers that are either based on more reliable sources than sites like xmenmovies wikia (nothing on that site has citations), or answers with more complete information and citations. Still, a helpful answer.

Comment: I understand, which is why I upvoted Edlothiad's answer for the far superior effort displayed. This question just seemed so trivially resolved...

Comment: Simple answers are best answers.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. 
As seen in the film she has show Mutant like ability in the film. Also in later on in the film Quicksilver states that Magneto is his biological father, which is true in comic lore if I'm not mistaken there is story-line(s) where Magneto is the father of Quicksilver and Scarlet Witch who are twins. But in Avengers: Age of Ultron I believe that he is not their father as during it's time of release the X-men and Avengers franchise rights where owned by two different company's(20th Century Fox and Disney respectively).

Comment: *"As seen in the film she has show Mutant like ability in the film"* - What is the mutant-like ability?